# Posts loop displaying the same post data

Tags: posts, get-posts

My first real day with Wordpress, it's not going well... I just have a simple loop where I wish to display some posts from a specific category. This is my code:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'category' => 2,
        'offset' => 0,
        'order' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $foodPosts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($foodPosts as $foodPost) : setup_postdata($foodPost); 
?>
    <div><?php the_permalink(); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

and this is the output:

```
http://10.0.1.174/mysite/?p=7
Cool post title
this is yet another food post

http://10.0.1.174/mysite/?p=7
Cool post title
this post is in the food category

http://10.0.1.174/mysite/?p=7
Cool post title
this is a post about food
```

So the content for each is correct, but some reason all the permalinks and titles are the same as the very first post. What's up?

Comment: The codex page for [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) explains why this is happening, see the examples on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `WP_Query` instead. So the code would be like:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat' => 2,
        'offset' => 0,
        'order' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts()) : while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();   
?>
    <div><?php the_permalink(); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Worked great, cheers. Wonder what the problem was with the standard methods